# CKEditor 5 - Style definition for UL

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have the style plugin installed on ckeditor5 and for elements with one level, like a paragraph, it works great but with something like a list, it doesn't (or doesn't for me!)  The reason seems to be that for something like

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

When in the editor, it sees you as in the li, because if I do my definitions as such

```
var definitions = 
[
  {
    name: 'Info box',
    element: 'p',
    classes: [ 'info-box' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item List',
    element: 'li',
    classes: [ 'item-list' ]
  },
];
```

The style is enabled when I'm in the list but when I pick it, it puts the style on the li, when I need it on the ul.

If I make the definition like this

```
var definitions = 
[
  {
    name: 'Info box',
    element: 'p',
    classes: [ 'info-box' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item List',
    element: 'ul',
    classes: [ 'item-list' ]
  },
];
```

It's never enabled, because it's never seen as in the UL, just the LI.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the content contains ul tags and not ol tags? Also look for the definition style for item-list and it will be cool if you could post it. I'm asking because probably in your style you add something like li.item-list { }

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GicuAftene  It's 100% for sure ul and not ol.  I'm pretty sure the class definition is irrelevant, I changed element: 'ul', to element: 'li', the style is available but when pressed, it put's the class on the li, not ul.

Comment: Can you do a tiny standalone example on codesandbox or a similar platform? It's easier to play around with the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed in Version 38 https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/14200#issuecomment-1556760672